# framework7 - How can I keep radio button choice when reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I am making a theme changer in my framework7 app, here is the code of color changer using radio button

```
<ul id="bluegr">
<label class="label-radio item-content">
<input type="radio" name="color-radio" value="blue" checked>
<div class="item-inner">
<div class="item-title">Blue</div>
</div>
</label>                  
</ul>

<ul id="graygr">
<label class="label-radio item-content">
<input type="radio" name="color-radio" value="gray">
<div class="item-inner">
<div class="item-title">Gray</div>
</div>
</label>
</ul>
```

And here is theme changer

```
<ul>
<li>
<label class="label-radio item-content">
<input type="radio" name="layout-radio" value="layout-dark" checked>
<div class="item-inner">
<div class="item-title">Dark</div>
</div>
</label>
</li>
<li>
<label class="label-radio item-content">
<input type="radio" name="layout-radio" value="layout-white">
<div class="item-inner">
<div class="item-title">Light</div>
</div>
</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the javascript of making those color and theme changer work

```
var myApp = new Framework7();
      var $$ = Dom7;
      $$('input[name="color-radio"]').on('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
          $$('.view').removeClass('theme-blue theme-gray theme-lightblue');
          $$('.view').addClass('theme-' + $$(this).val());
        }
      });
      $$('input[name="layout-radio"]').on('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
          $$('.view').removeClass('layout-dark layout-white');
          $$('.view').addClass(this.value);
        }
      });
```

Demo: http://qa.ftios.net/61-2

But when I try it out, it does change the color and theme but when I reload and it reverts back to default, so how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stored the selection anywhere so every time you reload the page the DOM will just revert back to the original state.

The simplest way would be to save the selection to localStorage and upon that module/page being called, you simply check to see if the item exists and if it does, based on its value, you would set the theme to that.